# How to show grand child record names in Pageblock Table

Tags: visualforce, controller

I have 4 objects
A,B,C,D

Visual force page written on A results showing in Page block table.
Relationships:
 A--->B Master Detail
 C---> Junction Object for B & D

REQ: Need to show D names along with object A values on that Visualforce page table.Because there is no relationship between A & D. Through D->c->B needs to achieve

Is this possible? If any solution with example please help me. This is high priority.

Comment: No chance in one query result. You will need a wrapper class.

Comment: Ok Thanks For your reply..do you have any example peace of code? Please share it with me..it is an urgent fix

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you need?

```
[SELECT D_Id__r.Name, B_Id__c, B_Id__r.A__r.Name 
FROM C 
WHERE B_Id__r.A__c IN : A_Id_Set ORDER BY B_Id__r.A__c]
```

This will return all D records that are conected to A. The issue could be that some will be "duplicated" as one D could be conected with many B and by that with many A.

This is for A(m) ---> (d)B, B(m) --> (d)C(d) <---(m)D